# Handle Recurring Payments for Pro sites ( WordPress plugin)

Tags: wordpress, payment-gateway, recurring-billing, wpmu, quickpay

I am developing payment gateway integration (Quickpay - http://quickpay.net/) for Pro Sites plugin (https://premium.wpmudev.org/project/pro-sites/). Unfortunately Quickpay doesn't support Auto recurring payments are their end. so I have to handle auto recurring payments at WordPress end.

Pro sites has functionality for handle recurring payments at website end? 
If yes can you please guide me how can I achieve that.

Thanks in advance.